# Не действует htaccess для ссылок с символами

Tags: .htaccess, urlencode

php:

```
$person = '❤#test#❤';
echo '<a target="_blank" href="/person/'.urlencode($person).'">'.$person.'</a>';
```

.htaccess:

```
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^person/([^/]*)$ /user_id/?id=$1 [QSA,L]
```

При переходе ссылка должна быть таким образом:

```
http://.../person/❤%23test%23❤
```

Выглядет таким образом:

```
http://.../user_id/?id=❤%23test%23❤
```

То есть когда имя пользователя символами `.htaccess` не действует а когда без символа то всё работает и ссылка правельная.

Comment: Это не дубль вопроса, там идет речь по php но я вяснил что проблема на .htaccess

Comment: Значит закройте тот вопрос, раз вы с ним разобрались.

Comment: Интересно, каким образом правило делающее проверку на `^user` должно работать на ссылки вида `person/...`